# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, paypal

I was integrating Paypal to my android application, and now it keeps crashing and is unable to even start. I used to stack trace to find my error and this is the error I got, unfortunately, I'm still not sure how to go about solving it.

Using: A converted Eclipse file to Android Studio

```
01-24 16:33:56.581 1581-1581/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService@b219deb0 with Intent { cmp=com.app.myapp/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service extras invalid.  Please check the docs.
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2507)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service extras invalid.  Please check the docs.
                                                 at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit (includes extras):

```
    package com.app.myapp;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
   import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
   import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
   import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
   import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

   import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;

   import java.math.BigDecimal;

   public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    TextView m_response;

    PayPalConfiguration m_configuration;
    // the id is the link to the paypal account, we have to create an app and get its id
    String m_paypalClientId = "AUa...yYPeJiy\n";
    Intent m_service;
    int m_paypalRequestCode = 999; // or any number you want

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

        m_configuration = new PayPalConfiguration()
                .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX) // sandbox for test, production for real
                .clientId(m_paypalClientId);

        m_service = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        Intent intent = m_service.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);// configuration above
        startService(m_service); // paypal service, listening to calls to paypal app
    }
    void pay(View view)
    {
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(10), "SGD", "Test payment with Paypal",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class); // it's not paypalpayment, it's paymentactivity !
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, m_paypalRequestCode);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == m_paypalRequestCode)
        {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                // we have to confirm that the payment worked to avoid fraud
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

                if(confirmation != null)
                {
                    String state = confirmation.getProofOfPayment().getState();

                    if(state.equals("approved")) // if the payment worked, the state equals approved
                        m_response.setText("payment approved");
                    else
                        m_response.setText("error in the payment");
                }
                else
                    m_response.setText("confirmation is null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Service extras invalid.  Please check the docs` - How are you starting the PayPal service? What extras are you passing to it when creating the intent?

Comment: @MichaelDodd Hi Michael, I have edited my question such that it shows the paypal extras now. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Remove `\n` from the end of your client id.

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks! I missed that and have taken away the \n! Although unfortunately it doesn't affect the error.